# Is it possible to keep the page title from actually appearing at the top of the page?

Tags: pages, title

I want the pages named and not left blank for organizational purposes, but can I keep the titles from actually showing up on the page? I've looked everywhere.

Comment: Don't include the `the_title` tag in the template file that renders the loop for the content in the pages. Also could it be you mean the title in the browser address bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Displaying the title is part of the code inside your theme. But you can remove (hide) the title from display by looking at the CSS 'class' or 'id' your theme assigns to the title. You do this with developer tools like Firebug.

Assume that the text of the title specifies the class of 'thetitle'. Add this CSS to your theme (via the additional CSS that the theme may allow):

```
.thetitle {display:none; }
```

If your theme does not allow 'additional CSS', then your best bet is to create a Child Theme for your theme, and add the above CSS to the `style.css` of your child theme. (You don't want to modify your theme's `style.css` file, as any changes you make would be overwritten with a theme update.)

Another option is to install a plugin that allows you to add additional CSS, if your theme does not support that. There are several that are available.

Comment: Thanks again Rick. Youre the man! I was looking for an option to modify the CSS, but it turns out I needed to upgrade my wordpress plan to have access to that. I got it now. Thank you very much!
P.S. Marked it with "correct answer" this time ;)

Comment: Do you know of an alternative to firebug? I checked it out and it says it's not available anymore. Im on Ubuntu using Chrome btw.

Comment: I use Firefox on a Windows 10 computer, with Firebug, although FF has it's own dev tools; just have gotten used to Firebug. As for dev tools on Chrome, the googles say https://developer.chrome.com/devtools . Assume the process will work on a nixbox.  And thanks for the 'correct answer'!